# How to find unconstrained minimizer of $f(x)$, $f$ convex when the gradient is not invertible and $0 \not\in \text{im}(\nabla f(x))$?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, maxima-minima

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex, differentiable function. We wish to find a minimizer to $f$.

Consider the unconstrained minimization problem:

$$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} f(x)$$

By the first order condition, we should have $\nabla f(x^*) = 0$, where $x^*$ is the global optima

**However, in many cases $\nabla f$ does not have an inverse (so we cannot use $x^* = \nabla f^{-1}(0)$), and $0 \not\in \text{im}(\nabla f(x))$, where $\text{im}$ denotes the image of $\nabla f$.**

A concrete example similar to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781331/minimization-of-log-sum-exponential-function-subject-to-constraints) is $f(x) = \log(\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n e^{\beta x_i}), \beta > 0$, in this case, $0 \notin \text{im}(\nabla f(x))$, and $\nabla f(x)$ is not a bijection. How do we find minimizer over all $\mathbb{R}^n$?

**How do we solve for the minimizer in these cases?**

Comment: In your example, if $n=1$, $f(x)=\beta x$ is not bounded below. One can show the same thing for more dimensions by taking all the $x_i$ equal.

Comment: If this can't be done exactly (which is often the case) you can use any number of numerical methods. These numerical methods generally take one of two forms: line search, or trust-region. I would suggest you take a look at Nocedal and Write's *Numerical Optimization* text. Some algorithms are Newton's method, quasi-Newtons method, Levenberg-Marquardt, etc. The most appropriate algorithm will depend on your problem specifics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a differentiable convex function $x_{*}$ is a global minimum if and only if $ \nabla f(x_*) = 0 $.

So you only need to solve the equation $\nabla f(x) = 0.$  If it doesn't have any solution this means $f$ does not have minimum !